# problem with facebook api

Tags: ios4, sdk, iphone-sdk-3.2

Any one know what's going wrong with facebook old Api?

I am using the facebook old Api in my app and it has been working fine for a couple of months but now when I connect to facebook the opening dialogue shows popup of facebook mobile connect.

When I enter user name and password the dialogue goes blank and won't disappear and because of that I'm not able to get session key and userId.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

The best solution is to update to the new api (facebook-ios-sdk), but currently I have live apps in AppStore and I'm having the same problem as you. I hope facebook fixed it but, I'm thinking uploading new version with new api... asap.

If anybody know a better solution please let us know.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there is any way to get session key from accessToken ?